# Store division of integers in float value C++

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point, int, division

I just wanted to ask what happens number wise if i do not typecast integers to float when storing in a float variable like this:

```
int32 IntVar1 = 100
int32 IntVar2 = 200
float FloatVar = IntVar1/IntVar2;
```

Currently i am doing this:

```
int32 IntVar1 = 100
int32 IntVar2 = 200
float FloatVar = float(IntVar1)/float(IntVar2);
```

But in the amount of code i have, this looks really retarded. I thought about changing my int variables to float, but i guess that would be a performance hit. And since the integer values are not supposed to hold any decimals, it feels like a complete waste.

So i wonder, are there any way that option 1 could be working? Or do i have to typecast OR change variables to float? (All typecasting pretty much makes the code unreadable)

Comment: is it more readable: float FloatVar = (float) IntVar1 / IntVar2; ?

Comment: Yes it is, but would this go over a division with even more values?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't worry too much about premature optimization. If it makes more sense for your values to be expressed as `float` types, go for it. If your program doesn't run as fast as you need, and you've profiled it and know that the floating point operations are the problem, then start thinking about how to speed it up.

I'd value readability over all of the casting, which seems to be your instinct as well.

Also, since this question is tagged C++, I think it's (unfortunately?) more idiomatic to do:

```
float FloatVar = static_cast<float>(IntVar1)/IntVar2
```

Comment: I guess you are right, being able to edit your code is very important, hehe! Thank you!

Why are you static casting? Are there any benefits from that?

Comment: @LilleCarl Take a look here: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#static-cast
Spoiler alert: It expresses your intentions more clearly and is easier to search for.

Comment: Another C++ variation: `float(IntVar1)/IntVar2`; constructor-style.

Comment: @MSalters +1 -- yet another option!

Answer (score 3):

Behold the magic of functions:

```
float div(int x, int y)
{
    return float(x) / float(y);
}
```

Now you can say:

```
int32 IntVar1 = 100
int32 IntVar2 = 200
float FloatVar = div(IntVar1, IntVar2);
```

Comment: Imho, that would end up giving me headache, but i see your point! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need at least one of those operands to be float, otherwise the division will be truncated. I usually cast the first operand:

```
float FloatVar = (float)IntVar1/IntVar2;
```

which, elegance-wise, isn't that bad.

Comment: Ah, so it is enough just typecasting one and then the other integers will autoconvert? (Id rather use c++ typecasting tho, c-style casting looks like it doesnt belong to anywhere)

Comment: Lets say i would want to do like this:
    int IntVar = FloatVar1/FloatVar2;
Then would they be converted to int before or after division?

Comment: Thank you Eric, helped me a lot =) I guess i should write a "demo" program of my function (commandline) so i can test my math without launching the entire system :)

EDIT: Will it floor or ceil? Or will it "floor(value+0.5f)"?

Comment: @LilleCarl, it will round either towards zero or towards minus infinity. It's implementation-defined which one.

Comment: Minus infinity? So it will always round down(floor?) Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

As per the ISO/IEC standard- **N3797** - section 5.6

> For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient
>   with any **fractional part discarded**; if the quotient a/b is
>   representable in the type of the result, (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a;
>   otherwise, the behavior of both a/b and a%b is undefined

The discarding of the fractional part is called **truncation towards zero**.

There is no wonder if the fractional part is discarded in

```
22/7
```